# Handle dependency between 2 tables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We load data into table Final_Schema.Final_Table_A through task scheduled at 6:00 am UTC assuming Stage_Table_A refreshes before 6:00 am on 1st of every month. If any upstream process delays, Stage_Table_A may partially refresh or not at all refreshes, during when we couldn’t produce data into Final_Table_A, resulting data latency. There are monthly/daily refresh tables (data load frequency of tables) in Stage & Final schema. Say if it’s monthly refresh, Stage_Table_A did not refresh before 6:00 am UTC on 1st day of month, task triggered as per schedule, loaded zero records in Final_Table_A. This case users rely on old data for a month.
How to effectively handle the dependency between two tables in 2 layers? We’re assuming Stage_Table_A refreshes before 6:00 am UTC on 1st day. How to remove this dependency just on assumption? Please suggest something alternate to CRON Schedule. Please suggest some feature in snowflake which can wait until Stage_Table_A is refreshed and then trigger final_Table_A load. Would Dynamic Tables in Snowflake could resolve this problem?

[image]

0

Comment: Hi - it’s not clear, to me, what you are asking or what you are trying to implement. If the load of the first table doesn’t finish by a given time do you want the second table to load or not?

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for responding. I wanted to load second table post first table load. But the dependency should NOT be on CRON schedule or any time assumption. Second table has to watch until first table is fully loaded and then start second table. Can any table or object type in Snowflake does the job?

Comment: Yes - just load each table using a separate task and then make the second task dependent on the first task

Comment: If your 2 tables are a stage table and a final table where the stage table has a stream over it, then you could run the task that loads your final table every minute with a WHEN clause that looks at whether the stream has data.  That task will do nothing until there is something in the stage table to execute.

Comment: Thank you Nick & Mike for the response. The stage table is loaded from Azure BLOB through Snowpipe. Stage table cannot have task. This is making dependency a challenge. Very often, final table task executes when Stage table is partially loaded, leading missing data in Final table. Is there any way, we can avoid this CRON schedule and set dependency appropriate. The problem with CRON is, we assume stage table refreshes before final task schedule, but sometimes not. Postponing schedule is not a solution, this happened several times, could not predict upstream.

Comment: What’s the issue with implementing @MikeWalton’s suggestion?

Comment: We have ~2000 distinct tables with similar dependency i.e., each final table have dependency on its corresponding stage table and this final table task is scheduled with some CRON schedule depending on the assumption the upstream or stage table could complete. This assumption is sucking us. The problem in particular to our case in implementing Mike Walton's solution is running ~2000 tasks every minute spikes our Snowflake credits.

Comment: And the other problem is there are ~45% of tables where final table has no stream, we just merge final table (from stage tables) using a generic stored procedure.